# Ubuntu 22.04 Very slow boot times on Late 2012 Mac Mini

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, mac-mini

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a late 2012 Mac Mini i5 dual core. 16 gigs ram.  It has a SSD drive and an external usb 3.0 hard drive mounted.

My entire boot time to the desktop is about 5 minutes. I'm new to Ubuntu.  Are these boot times normal? Is there anything I can do to speed it up or is this just the normal boot time for a old Mac Mini?

systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @2min 36.869s
└─multi-user.target @2min 36.868s
  └─docker.service @1min 20.459s +1min 16.407s
    └─containerd.service @41.955s +38.462s
      └─network.target @41.917s
        └─NetworkManager.service @34.038s +7.878s
          └─dbus.service @34.031s
            └─basic.target @33.639s
              └─sockets.target @33.639s
                └─snapd.socket @33.636s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @33.217s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @32.633s +583ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @31.951s +528ms
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @6.163s +25.729s
                          └─systemd-journald.service @5.408s +733ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @5.323s
                              └─system.slice @5.237s
                                └─-.slice @5.237s
```

system-analyze

```
Startup finished in 8.392s (kernel) + 2min 36.936s (userspace) = 2min 45.329s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 36.869s in userspace
```

system-analyze blame

```
2min 45.310s apt-daily-upgrade.service
1min 41.620s e2scrub_reap.service
1min 16.407s docker.service
     55.427s smbd.service
     51.174s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     38.462s containerd.service
     31.269s snapd.service
     25.729s systemd-journal-flush.service
     22.778s networkd-dispatcher.service
     19.442s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     18.606s udisks2.service
     16.827s dev-sda2.device
     16.185s accounts-daemon.service
     14.320s ModemManager.service
     14.158s dev-loop19.device
     13.209s nmbd.service
     12.964s dev-loop18.device
     12.964s dev-loop23.device
     12.859s dev-loop22.device
     12.767s dev-loop21.device
     12.454s dev-loop8.device
     12.006s dev-loop20.device
     11.592s dev-loop13.device
     11.537s dev-loop14.device
     11.457s dev-loop11.device
     11.363s dev-loop9.device
     10.972s dev-loop12.device
     10.773s dev-loop17.device
     10.632s dev-loop15.device
     10.537s dev-loop10.device
      9.687s dev-loop7.device
      9.368s power-profiles-daemon.service
      9.112s fwupd.service
      8.849s polkit.service
      8.747s dev-loop16.device
      8.605s dev-loop2.device
      8.258s user@1000.service
      8.094s avahi-daemon.service
      8.090s bluetooth.service
      7.987s gdm.service
      7.979s dev-loop0.device
      7.878s NetworkManager.service
      7.564s dev-loop3.device
      7.555s dev-loop6.device
      7.545s dev-loop4.device
      7.476s dev-loop5.device
      7.411s switcheroo-control.service
      7.402s thermald.service
      7.395s systemd-logind.service
      7.394s wpa_supplicant.service
      5.676s gpu-manager.service
      5.375s xrdp.service
      5.102s dev-loop1.device
      4.990s mnt-FatNAS.mount
      4.489s systemd-udevd.service
      4.443s snapd.apparmor.service
      4.151s apport.service
      3.767s man-db.service
      3.743s systemd-rfkill.service
      3.588s systemd-resolved.service
      3.545s rsyslog.service
      3.350s xrdp-sesman.service
      2.121s apparmor.service
      2.091s systemd-sysctl.service
      1.829s grub-common.service
      1.600s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
      1.584s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.576s packagekit.service
      1.401s snapd.seeded.service
      1.349s snap-brave-297.mount
      1.338s snap-brave-295.mount
      1.331s snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-141.mount
      1.327s snap-bare-5.mount
      1.264s snap-core22-864.mount
      1.247s snap-core18-2790.mount
      1.224s snap-core20-1974.mount
      1.214s snap-core20-2015.mount
      1.170s snap-core22-858.mount
      1.167s snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-120.mount
      1.159s update-notifier-download.service
      1.151s colord.service
      1.150s snap-cups-980.mount
      1.140s snap-firefox-3252.mount
      1.105s snap-firefox-3290.mount
      1.072s systemd-random-seed.service
      1.067s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
      1.053s snap-home\x2dmedia\x2dserver-53.mount
      1.015s systemd-sysusers.service
       995ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8430\x2dB110.service
       990ms snap-snapd-20092.mount
       989ms upower.service
       927ms bolt.service
       924ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
       901ms snap-postman-227.mount
       895ms snap-vlc-3078.mount
       893ms plymouth-start.service
       891ms snap-postman-229.mount
       801ms snap-snap\x2dstore-959.mount
       785ms snap-snapd-20290.mount
       766ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-83.mount
       733ms systemd-journald.service
       727ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       722ms snap-vlc-3721.mount
       654ms kerneloops.service
       599ms keyboard-setup.service
       583ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       528ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       527ms systemd-binfmt.service
       514ms fwupd-refresh.service
       494ms swapfile.swap
       483ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       475ms homebridge.service
       461ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       445ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       365ms systemd-oomd.service
       342ms ufw.service
       341ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       276ms rtkit-daemon.service
       258ms modprobe@drm.service
       251ms boot-efi.mount
       238ms setvtrgb.service
       221ms openvpn.service
       202ms alsa-restore.service
       157ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       130ms plymouth-read-write.service
       114ms dev-hugepages.mount
       112ms dev-mqueue.mount
       110ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       108ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
        99ms console-setup.service
        99ms motd-news.service
        93ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
        73ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        72ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        34ms cups.service
        32ms modprobe@configfs.service
        28ms modprobe@fuse.service
        25ms docker.socket
        22ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
        10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms snapd.socket
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```